# spark parquet - How to load LZO compressed parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, load, parquet, lzo

I have parquet file locally saved, loaded by:

```
val catDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("data.lzo.parquet")
```

It recognize the schema but each query or actions return the same below error:

> parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block
>   -1

Comment: I have also tried to set my SQLCtx  as val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=lzo")  ...but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Loading a parquet file as dataframe is as simple as you've stated

```
val catDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("data.parquet")
```

Your above code should work. Please check whether the parquet location is correct

Comment: thanks for the answer...actually the problem involved in: parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1  ...i suppose is something related to LZO parquet compression...do u know something about this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

LZO (parquet) compression issues, resolved adding dependency to sbt config:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.anarres.lzo" % "lzo-hadoop" % "1.0.0")
```

Hope will be usefull for someone.